# How to get NSString that xml from the url contain?

Tags: ios, xml, cocoa, url

I know how to parse NSString object with DOM parser, but i have no idea how to get that NSString from xml file on web.

Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `NSString` based on online `.xml` file:

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/feed.xml"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *theXML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:theURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, was about to answer it myself coz found the answer. Thnx anyway!